# Use ContentProvider to run code on app startup

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm making an android library and I want to run some initialization code when the application starts.

In some cases, it might be a little difficult for the developer(using my library) to implement a custom application class. AFAIK, the `ContenProvider` codes start before application starts and does not need any custom implementation done by the developer using my library.

The question is, **Can I use ContentProvider to run code at Application's start up?**

I simply create a provider class:

```
class ExampleProvider : ContentProvider() {

    override fun onCreate(): Boolean {

        // run code at startup and do initialization

        return true
    }

    ...

    // Ignore other methods and return null or 0
}
```

And add the manifest tag.

And it will run before the application starts up. (**Without the need of Custom Application class**) But will it always behave like this and run code before app starts? Is there any case that ContentProviders will not launch at app startup?

---

#### TL; DR

How an android library can run code at application startup, without asking developers to implement a custom Application class?

Comment: Content providers dont run at app startup. What makes you think so?

Comment: `difficult for the user to implement a custom application class`. Users of apps cannot implement classes.

Comment: `want to run some initialization code in my library when the application starts.`. Then call the init function in onCreate().

Comment: ContentProvider's classes do run before application code. Like `FirebaseInitProvider`

Comment: By custom app class, I mean a class that extends `android.app.Application` as a custom Application class

Comment: There's no `init` or `onCreate` for a library since it's not allowed to customize application class by itself. The user's manifest file decides what to be as the application class. So Either tell the user to do so, or find another way.

Comment: And by user, I mean users of the library which are in fact, developers.

Comment: You should tell that at the start of your post. You even did not tell what your library has to do with the content provider you are talking about. Very confusing post on this way.

Comment: You're right. I've made the question more clear. Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. See the working example- https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:startup/startup-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/startup/InitializationProvider.java

Comment: @SouravBagchi  I believe you're right. Since the WorkManager and Firebase are using this feature as well. Feel free to post an answer for this so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently Android has provided a [startup library](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/app-startup) to initialize components at application startup. If you see the [source code](https://cs.android.com/androidx/platform/frameworks/support/+/androidx-master-dev:startup/startup-runtime/src/main/java/androidx/startup/InitializationProvider.java) of that library, you will see they use `ContentProvider` to start the library at startup.